# How to split a filename based on the latest occurrence of repeated delimiters? (Python)

Tags: python, split, delimiter

How can I split a filename based on the latest occurrence of a repeated delimiter? Such that:

Example File List:

```
abc_123
abc_123_d4
abc__123  (2 underscores)
abc_123__d4  (2 underscores)
abc____123  (4 underscores)
```

Expected Outcome:

```
abc, 123
abc, 123, d4
abc_, 123 (1 underscore)
abc, 123_, d4 (1 underscore)
abc___, 123 (3 underscores)
```

Using:

```
filename.split("_")
```

would output:

```
abc, 123
abc, 123, d4
abc, 123
abc, 123, d4
abc, 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'_(?!_)')

pattern.split('abc_123')  # ['abc', '123']
pattern.split('abc_123_d4')  # ['abc', '123', 'd4']
pattern.split('abc__123')  # ['abc_', '123']
pattern.split('abc_123__d4')  # ['abc', '123_', 'd4']
pattern.split('abc____123')  # ['abc___', '123']
```

The regex `_(?!_)` matches an underscore that is not followed by another underscore

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to match only single occurrences of a delimiter (ignore consecutive repeats) , would it be:
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\_)\_(?!\_)')